How to calculate required "reserved deposit" to register a parachain on Kusama with adder-collator genesis state and code?
If a user follows the instructions in the Polkadot Wiki it is possible to Reserve ParaID and it reserves 40 KSM with the account (it is possible to deregister if necessary), but when they follow the next step to Register Parachain State and Code as shown in the extract below:

If they use the same account using the ParaID that was just reserved and they upload the initial genesis state (72 bytes) and genesis WASM code (15,593 bytes) for adder-collator it calculates a reserved deposit of 45.222999994777 KSM and when they submit that extrinsic registrar::register it says the transaction fee will be 0.05282 KSM, but even if they have a transferable balance of 80 KSM (that is almost twice as large as the required reserved deposit shown in the UI) it returns an error system.ExtrinsicFailedbalances.LiquidityRestrictions (which is shown as Account liquidity restrictions prevent withdrawal. in the extrinsic on Subscan).
Moderators here though that what I mostly described above is a duplicate of this other post, where they encountered a similar error InsufficientBalance when they submit the registrar::register, and where they say they found the cause was due to the latest Polkadot SDK source code that calculates the "reserved deposit" based on MAX_CODE_SIZE (3_145_728 = 3 MB), which they say meant they needed a "reserved deposit" of 0.001 DOT per byte * 3_145_728 = 3145.728 DOT (~20289.95 USD on 10th June 2024), but that the Polkadot-JS Apps UI doesn't reflect this change.
I checked the open issues of the Polkadot-JS Apps repository and did not find any issue that had reported that the incorrect reserved deposit was shown in the Polkadot-JS Apps UI. So I have created an issue here.
I believe they calculated it based on https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-guides-coretime-parachains#register-parachain-state-and-code, where the reserved deposit is calculated here under DataDepositPerByte, where pub const DataDepositPerByte: Balance = 1 * CENTS; as shown here, which corresponds to the following as shown here for Rococo (which would be the same for Kusama), then CENTS equals 33_333_333, and that corresponds to Kusama: 0.000333 KSM per byte that is shown here
pub const UNITS: Balance = 1_000_000_000_000;
pub const CENTS: Balance = UNITS / 30_000;

Where the reserved deposit is calculated here the per_byte_fee equals 33_333_333 (0.000333 KSM), and the deposit equals the ParaDeposit (the deposit to be paid to run an on-demand parachain, which includes the cost for storing the genesis head and validation code) of pub const ParaDeposit: Balance = 40 * UNITS; (which is 40 KSM used earlier to Reserve ParaID) for Rococo or Kusama as shown here, plus the per_byte_fee * length of the genesis head data (where the contents of the "genesis" file is 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011b4d03dd8c01f1049143cf9c4c817e4b167f1d1b83e5c6f0f10d89ba1e7bce that has a length of 146), plus the per_byte_fee * potential to store validation code of a size up to the max_code_size (measured in bytes), which is defined here and has a value of pub const MAX_CODE_SIZE: u32 = 3 * 1024 * 1024; (which is 3_145_728) as shown here, so that would be: 40 KSM + (0.000333 KSM * 146) + (0.000333 KSM * 3_145_728) = 1087.576042 KSM (~31061.17 USD on 10th June 2024).
let per_byte_fee = T::DataDepositPerByte::get();
let deposit = T::ParaDeposit::get()
.saturating_add(per_byte_fee.saturating_mul((genesis_head.0.len() as u32).into()))
.saturating_add(per_byte_fee.saturating_mul(config.max_code_size.into()));

Does that appear to be correct? If so then the reserved deposit that is required to register a parachain on Kusama with the adder-collator genesis state and code from the Polkadot SDK is 1087.576042 KSM.

I have reopened this. Find the previous dup question link here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/11553/start-a-parachain-crowd-loan-shows-before-using-this-registered-paraid-you-nee

The Wiki needs an update.
Due to the issue discussed here https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/2372 the deposit needed defaults to MAX_CODE_SIZE https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/3020
Thanks to Chopsticks https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/chopsticks, I was able to determine the total KSM required for registering ParaID and uploading wasm code is 1,088.6086 KSM for the current version of runtime (1.2.5).
The code registration takes around 5 KSM in fee, so need to account for that as well.


your a legend!  thanks!!

this account has at least ~1400 KSM "transferable balance", which is more than required 1,088.575998951424 KSM fee for "reserve deposit", but still got LiquidityRestrictions error in extrinsic https://kusama.subscan.io/extrinsic/24878313-2 when try to "register parathread" in Polkadot.js against ParaId 3353 after they registered that ParaId with 40 KSM. they uploaded adder-collator genesis wasm and initial state after building latest Polkadot SDK and clicking submit. they even transferred 1200 KSM to another account and back to prove sufficient transferrable balance. do u know why?
